# Connection refused on Docker tutorial get started part 4

Tags: docker, virtualbox, docker-machine

I don't understand what I missed.

docker.compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    image: svezday/friendlyhello:part-1
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - webnet
  visualizer:
    image: dockersamples/visualizer:stable
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

Dockerfile

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:2.7-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 80

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME World

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from redis import Redis, RedisError
import os
import socket

# Connect to Redis
redis = Redis(host="redis", db=0, socket_connect_timeout=2, socket_timeout=2)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    try:
        visits = redis.incr("counter")
    except RedisError:
        visits = "<i>cannot connect to Redis, counter disabled</i>"

    html = "<h3>Hello {name}!</h3>"            "<b>Hostname:</b> {hostname}<br/>"            "<b>Visits:</b> {visits}"
    return html.format(name=os.getenv("NAME", "world"), hostname=socket.gethostname(), visits=visits)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

I'm on ubuntu 18, with vitualbox.

This is the vm

```
NAME    ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER     ERRORS
myvm1   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v18.09.0
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask
Redis
myvm2   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.101:2376           Unknown    Unable to query docker version: Get https://192.168.99.101:2376/v1.15/version: x509: certificate is valid for 192.168.99.103, not 192.168.99.101
```

docker-machine ssh myvm1

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.99.101:2377 getStartNow
```

docker-machine ssh myvm2

```
docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-29dkoqd6tskoqszzrdpcnw0nbmrgbrw9xr27yoxtvapodk6qmg-3tv01eh1ts0n97s5c5zq7q4ju 192.168.99.100:2377
```

docker-machine ssh myvm1

```
 docker stack deploy -c docker.compose.yml getStartNow
```

docker stack ls

```
NAME                SERVICES            ORCHESTRATOR
getStartNow         2                   Swarm
```

docker service ls

```
ID                  NAME                     MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                             PORTS
w9l0khipey4v        getStartNow_visualizer   replicated          1/1                 dockersamples/visualizer:stable   *:8080->8080/tcp
3yoifm7inujf        getStartNow_web          replicated          5/5                 svezday/friendlyhello:part-1      *:80->80/tcp
```

AND HERE IS MY PROBLEM

curl http://192.168.99.100:80

```
 curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 80: Connection refused
```

curl http://192.168.99.100:8080

```
 curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 8080: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem.
I followed Elavaud solution [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/get-started-part-4-connection-refused-from-node-on-virtual-machine/62511/10) and it worked for me.

So:

1. I downloaded boot2docker.iso from [here](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/tag/v18.06.1-ce)
2. Check active virtual-machine

   `docker-machine ls`
3. destroy all virtual machines (myvm1 and myvm2)

   `docker-machine rm $(docker-machine ls -q)`
4. Create again the virtual-machines specifying the path of your downloaded boot2docker.iso

`docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --virtualbox-boot2docker-url path_to_your_boot2docker.iso virtual_machine_name`

In my case the path was ~/Downloads/boot2docker.iso so i did

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --virtualbox-boot2docker-url ~/Downloads/boot2docker.iso myvm1

docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --virtualbox-boot2docker-url ~/Downloads/boot2docker.iso myvm2
```

5. Start again get started part-4

Last think, I saw your docker-compose.yml  is differente from docker-compose.yml created in get_started part3. I don't know if that could be the problem.
In my case I used the same docker-compose.yml in get_started part3, so when I access to my app i use the port 4000

```
curl http://192.168.99.101:4000/
```

Comment: Thats right. Just to clarify the problem here, this is the root cause: [18.09.0 iso breaks swarm ingress](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4608). With current ISO any publishing of swarm ports in virtualbox created docker-machine VM's won't respond. As stated above the solution is to downgrade boot2docker.iso to v18.06.1-ce.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, but found a slightly simpler solution; rather than downloading boot2docker and pointing to it on your machine, you can just set the `virtualbox-boot2docker-url` flag to a url for the downgraded version; e.g.:

```sh
docker-machine create myvm1 --virtualbox-boot2docker-url "https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v18.06.1-ce/boot2docker.iso"
```

```sh
docker-machine create myvm2 --virtualbox-boot2docker-url "https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v18.06.1-ce/boot2docker.iso"
```