# Docker connection issues - refused to connect

Tags: docker, containers, virtualbox

I'm using Mac OSX and I'm on [part 4 of the Docker tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/), but I cannot access the site through my web browser. When I visit either IP address given from the `docker-machine ls` command I get a "this site can't be reached" error. If I specify port 2377, such as `http://192.168.99.100:2377/` (also used port 2376) I can at least connect but it results in a "192.168.99.100 sent an invalid response" error message.

When I try a curl request to both port 80 and 8080 it fails

```
curl http://192.168.99.100:80
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 80: Connection refused
```

If I specify port 2376 or 2377 it will connect, but I don't get any content back, which seems to coincide with the "invalid response" error I get when visiting directly from my web browser

```
curl --verbose 192.168.99.100:2376
* Rebuilt URL to: 192.168.99.100:2376/
*   Trying 192.168.99.100...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.99.100 (192.168.99.100) port 2376 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.99.100:2376
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 

* Connection #0 to host 192.168.99.100 left intact
```

Here's the output when I run `docker-machine ls`

```
NAME    ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER        ERRORS
myvm1   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v18.06.1-ce   
myvm2   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.101:2376           v18.06.1-ce
```

I think I have a port mapping issue with the VM's, but I'm not sure what to do. I tried [the accepted answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451285/connection-refused-on-docker-tutorial-get-started-part-4), but still no luck.

**Update**

I tried port forwarding as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47989962/how-to-open-port-7946-and-4789-in-a-vm-which-is-created-by-docker-machine), but had no luck with that either. I added the following and verified in the VirtualBox manager that the forwarding rules are present

```
VBoxManage controlvm "myvm1" natpf1 "tcp-port8000,tcp,,80,,80";
VBoxManage controlvm "myvm2" natpf1 "tcp-port8000,tcp,,80,,80";
```

I've also added forwarding for port 7946 TCP/UDP and Port 4789 UDP to each of the two vm's

Comment: I'm not sure manually forwarding those ports is a good way to go. I believe the swarm routing mesh uses it's own ports for internal routing anyway, but you may end up with an unpredictable system if you are a routing ports manually without knowing exactly what will happen.

Comment: Is your cluster healthy? Running `docker node ls`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the same problem today when study part4. After a long time searching for solutions but didn't work, then I checked my `docker-compose.yml` file to see the ports mapping and found the right port. For me is `curl -v http://192.168.99.100:4000`, and it worked:

[image]

Comment: That worked, thanks! I should've known I had to specify port 4000 after having to do that in the prior sections of the tutorial.